# Angular2 checkbox not updating when value changes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I've got a checkbox:

```
<input [name]="persona" type="checkbox" [value]="r.id" (ngModelChange)="updateSingleId(r)" [(ngModel)]="r.selected" (change)="deselectLast()"  />
```

In the ngModelChange, when the user tries to deselect, we pop up an ng2-bootstrap modal and ask the user if they're sure they want to deselect.  If they say no, we want to re-select the checkbox.

Before when this was being done with a javascript `confirm()`, I could just pass the event into the function and stopPropogation on it, but ng2-bootstrap's modals don't work like that.

So anyway, if the user clicks no, I set selected back to true on that object:

```
this.question.personaSelection.forEach(x => {
    if (this.previousSelection.filter(y => y === x.id).length > 0) {
        x.selected = true;
    } else {
        x.selected = false;
    }
});
```

. `r` in the checkbox is an object in `this.question.personaSelection`.  The checkboxes are in an `*ngFor`.  That little function resets all of the checkboxes back to their value before the user tried to deselect one.

When debugging, I can verify that the `question.personaSelection`s `selected` property is correct on everything, but the checkbox isn't being set back to checked.

What am I missing?  I also tried using `[checked]="r.selected"` on the checkboxes but that didn't work, and I tried setting ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush and manually detect changes after changing `x.selected`.

Comment: shouldn't [(ngModel)]="r.selected" be [ngModel]="r.selected"?

Comment: But then the ngModelChange wouldn't fire?

Comment: you should be able to use like this (ngModelChange)="updateSingleId(r)" [ngModel]="r.selected", what is r.id in [value], i think it should be boolean value.

Comment: I tried taking the parentheses off of the ngModel and it didn't fix it.  It actually seems to have had no effect... and r.id is a number

Comment: have you tried binding to checked? `[checked]="r.selected"
 (change)="r.selected = !r.selected"`

Comment: Well I already have functions bound to (change), so I can't do that.  However, I can verify by looking at the component data in Augury that r.selected is set to true when the checkbox is showing false, even after binding to checked.